# ConvertFrom-Json $array only get the first element?

Tags: powershell

The following statement

```
'[{"A":123}, {"B":456}]' | ConvertFrom-Json
```

returns

```
  A
  -
123
```

The second one is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not missing, just not displayed by default.

```
PS C:\> '[{"A":123}, {"B":456}]' | ConvertFrom-Json | Format-List *

A : 123

B : 456
```

```
PS C:\> '[{"A":123}, {"B":456}]' | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -Property *


Count          : 2
Length         : 2
LongLength     : 2
Rank           : 1
SyncRoot       : {@{A=123}, @{B=456}}
IsReadOnly     : False
IsFixedSize    : True
IsSynchronized : False
```